# Qt failed to link to qtcore

Tags: windows, qt, cmake

I'm trying to build http://anongit.kde.org/trojita on Windows.

I have Mingw 4.4 Qt 4.8.4 and CMake 2.8.11.1 installed.

The link step fails with a dozen of errors like this:

```
qwwsmtpclient.cpp:438: undefined reference to `_imp___ZNK7QString8endsWithERKS_N2Qt15CaseSensitivityE'
```

Here is the failing command:

```
d:\MinGW\4.4\bin\g++.exe   -Wall -g -g    -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles\test_Composer_Submission.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -o test_Composer_Submission.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libtest_Composer_Submission.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  libImap.a libMSA.a libStreams.a libCommon.a libComposer.a libtest_LibMailboxSync.a h:\Qt\4.8.4\lib\libQtNetworkd4.a h:\Qt\4.8.4\lib\libQtSqld4.a h:\Qt\4.8.4\lib\libQtTestd4.a h:\Qt\4.8.4\lib\libQtGuid4.a libImap.a h:\Qt\4.8.4\lib\libQtNetworkd4.a h:\Qt\4.8.4\lib\libQtSqld4.a h:\Qt\4.8.4\lib\libQtCored4.a libComposer.a libMSA.a libStreams.a libCommon.a libqwwsmtpclient.a libMimetypesQt4.a h:\Qt\4.8.4\lib\libQtGuid4.a -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32
```

I checked and libQtCored4 contains  `__imp___ZNK7QString8endsWithERKS_N2Qt15CaseSensitivityE` but not `_imp___ZNK7QString8endsWithERKS_N2Qt15CaseSensitivityE`

What might be the issue?

Full log here http://paste.debian.net/13366/

Comment: Is the Qt compiled with mingw as well? One cannot mix c++ code compiled with msvc and mingw. As you're linking statically, the order in which the libs are specified on the linker line might matter.

Comment: yep i have Qt for MinGW

Comment: you were right, after i placed h:\Qt\4.8.4\lib\libQtCored4.a h:\Qt\4.8.4\lib\libQtNetworkd4.a last it linked!